# Is there a precedent of Hamas allowing the Red Cross to visit their hostages?

Tags: hamas

It seems the Red Cross is operative in the Gaza Strip, so Hamas doesn't object in principle to their activity, quite the opposite, they depend on humanitarian aid, and they're accepting it readily, while the RC are not allowed to visit the Israeli hostages:

JERUSALEM, Oct 26 ([Reuters](https://%20https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/bedouin-family-hopes-four-relatives-held-gaza-will-return-in-peace-2023-10-26/)) - Ali Ziadna, from the Israeli Bedouin city of Rahat, has given insulin to the Red Cross, hoping they will give it to his brother whom he said is one of more than 200 hostages taken in Israel by Hamas gunmen on Oct. 7 and dragged into captivity in Gaza.

"He's diabetic," Ziadna told Reuters in a phone interview after a meeting with the Israeli president in Jerusalem. "Without it, his sugar could drop and he could collapse."

Yet Hamas claims to treat the hostages humanely. Wouldn't be in this case the logical to allow the Red Cross (or any humanitarian organization already operating in Gaza) to visit the hostages?

Did it ever happen in previously that Hamas allowed the Red Cross to visit hostages or prisoners?

Comment: I detest Hamas, but maybe they simply don't see many advantages for them there. What advantages do you see for them?

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that Hamas isn't lying about the treatment of hostages? They are an antisemitic terrorist org and have shown how they are willing to treat civilians in the brutal massacres on 7.10.

Comment: @tim i dont know. there was a case of Shani Louk, a German citizen. there was a confusion whether she is alive. yesterday it seems evidence was found that she died on the first day.. If Hamas wants to convince us that they're humane, why not publish at least the names of the hostages? That's the most basic thing.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution proof that theyre indeed treating the hostages humanely, as they claim?

Comment: "proof that theyre indeed treating the hostages humanely" That could be added to the question then. The question is basically how big of an advantage proving that is in a complex hostage and war situation.

Comment: You answer yourself the title Q. As for "best strategy" that's opinion based. Allowing the Red Cross to visit would perhaps make the hostages location more easy for Israel to locate. Israel did manage to free one hostage recently by special ops.

Comment: It's possible that they're concerned that this might leak information about the locations of the hostages to the Israeli military

Comment: @Fizz  they even declined to give lists of hostage names or letters from them. i  wonder if were there cases when the Hamas did allow the Red Cross near hostages and prisoners? not just Israelis, but captured Fatah members? any cooperation?

Comment: For reference, the [Red Cross has arranged visits to Palestinians detained in Israel](https://efe.com/en/other-news/2023-09-02/red-cross-calls-on-israel-to-ensure-right-to-family-visits-of-palestinian-prisoners/), although Israel sometimes imposes restrictions on these visits.

Comment: I would assume the precise location of the hostages is secret and Hamas wants to keep it that way because otherwise there would be an Israeli raid on the location. So very few people know where the hostages are kept.

Comment: Why not make the title match the body?  Something like *Reasons for Hamas policy with regards to Red Cross hostage access?*.  That said, this is not a question that can be answered with certainty in the absence of Hamas statements - VTC.  Though a good guess (about operational location security is being made in comments).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica one day I'll write a question you dont want to VTC :)

Comment: @Angriffsreiher It is a bit borderline in this, but, yes, there is a fairly strong tendency here to try to close questions for which it is difficult to find objective basis for answers.  Now, sometimes with governments that is a fallacy:  journalists cover them, opposition figures give briefings, leaks happen, etc... On the other end of the spectrum is "Why did person X carry out weird act Y?"  That requires mind reading.  The actions of a terrorist group with limited unbiased coverage and no effective local journalistic fact finding ends somewhat more in the 2nd bin than the 1st.

Comment: I fail to comprehend how asking what Hama's position is on allowing Red Cross visits to hostages can in any way be "opinion based".  And given [**WHO calls for immediate release, access to, and medical support for hostages taken by Hamas**](https://www.who.int/news/item/25-10-2023-who-calls-for-immediate-release--access-to--and-medical-support-for-hostages-taken-by-hamas) that there is no source available anywhere in any language that has no response at all from any person or organization associated in any way with Hamas that could be use to at least infer a Hamas policy WRT the Red Cross here

Comment: Close vote retracted.  No problem w asking on precedents.